# What are the hidden achievements in XCOM: Enemy Unknown?

Tags: achievements, xcom-enemy-unknown

Steam lists the game as having 60 achievements, but only ~38 actually show up in the achievement list to start with.

What "secret" achievements are there, and what are the requirements to unlock them?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can see the full list of Steam achievements [at the steam site](http://steamcommunity.com/stats/XCOMEnemyUnknown/achievements).

Out of the 60 achievements there are 20 that don't have a description. 10 of them are plot related achievements and you will unlock all of them (except from the Firestorm one) if you finish the original game:

- **Prisoner of War**: Capture a live alien.
- **The Gatekeeper**: Stun an Outsider.
- **X Marks the Spot**: Uncover the alien base's location.
- **Off My Planet**: Recover the Hyperwave Beacon.
- **Ride the Lightning**: Build a Firestorm. (not essential for the plot)
- **See All, Know All**: Build the Hyperwave Relay.
- **Beyond the Veil**: Find a soldier with the Gift.
- **And Hell's Coming With Me**: Successfully assault an Overseer UFO.
- **On the Shoulders of Giants**: Build the Gollop Chamber.
- **The Volunteer**: Make contact with the Ethereal hive mind.

**UPDATE:**

There are 10 more that don't have a description, 5 of them are related to the slingshot DLC, those are:

- **New Friend**: Complete Friends in Low Places.
- **Bait the Hook**: Complete Confounding Light.
- **The Bigger They Are**: Complete Gangplank.
- **Rising Dragon**: Take your new ally into the final challenge.
- **All Aboard**: Complete Confounding Light with more than 3 turns left on the timer.

The other 5 do not appear on the [xbox 360 version](http://www.xbox360achievements.org/game/xcom-enemy-unknown/achievements/) or the [PS3 version](http://www.ps3trophies.org/game/xcom-enemy-unknown/trophies/), and have 0% completion, which means that nobody was able to get them, just as it was with the above 5 before the release of the slingshot DLC, those are:

- **Disaster Averted**: Complete Deluge.
- **The Chase Is On**: Complete Portent.
- **Great Minds Think Alike**: Complete Furies.
- **No Sweat**: Complete Deluge without activating more than 2 valves.
- **Saved to Savior**: Have your newest ally volunteer for the most difficult duty.

As you can see, their description, [taken from here](http://www.giantbomb.com/xcom-enemy-unknown/61-37152/achievements/), makes no sense regarding to the game. With the history regarding the slingshot DLC they are probably related to a future DLC.

Comment: Those last five are for the three special missions featuring Annette Durand. They were originally intended to be a second DLC pack, but were reworked to become part of the Enemy Within expansion instead.

Answer (score 1):

Need to get more info on this as I've got 33 of 60. And can see some that haven't been achieved, but not all of them.

Here's the one's I know:

---

- **Ain't No Cavalry Comin'**: Have a soldier survive every mission in a full game.
- **All Employees Must Wash Hands…**: In a single game, complete every Autopsy.
- **All Together Now**: Get satellite coverage over every country on one continent.
- **And Hell's Coming With Me**: Successfully assault an Overseer UFO.
- **And So It Begins…**: Complete the tutorial mission.
- **Angel of Death**: Kill an alien while flying. Single player only.
- **As A Scalpel**: Earn the "Excellent" rating in every performance category on a terror mission.
- **Bada Boom**: Kill 50 aliens with explosive weapons.
- **Beyond the Veil**: Find a soldier with the Gift.
- **Bubonic**: Play a multiplayer match against someone with this achievement.
- **Combat Ready**: Build an item.
- **A Continental Fellow**: Win the game from each of the 5 starting locations.
- **Drums in the Deep**: Gain access to the lowest level in your base.
- **Earth First**: Beat the game on Classic difficulty.
- **Edison**: In a single game, complete every Research Project.
- **Eye in the Sky**: Launch a Satellite.
- **Flight of the Valkyries**: Win a mission with an all-female squad. Single player only.
- **The Gatekeeper**: Stun an Outsider.
- **Happy to Oblige**: Fulfill a Council request.
- **The Hardest Road**: Advance one of your soldiers to Colonel rank.
- **Humanity's Savior**: Beat the game on any difficulty.
- **Hunter/Killer**: In a single game, shoot down one of each alien craft.
- **Lone Wolf**: Clear a UFO crash site with one soldier on Classic or Impossible difficulty.
- **Man No More**: Build a suit of powered armor.
- **Meet New People. Then Kill Them.**: Win a multiplayer match.
- **No Looking Back**: Beat the game in Ironman mode on Classic or Impossible Difficulty.
- **Off My Planet**: Recover the Hyperwave Beacon.
- **On the Shoulders of Giants**: Build the Gollop Chamber.
- **One Gun at a Time**: Staff the Engineering Department with 80 engineers.
- **Oppenheimer**: Staff the Research Labs with 80 scientists.
- **Our Finest Hour**: Beat the game on Impossible difficulty.
- **Pale Horse**: Kill 500 aliens.
- **Prisoner of War**: Capture a live alien.
- **Ride the Lightning**: Build a Firestorm.
- **See All, Know All**: Build the Hyperwave Relay.
- **Shooting Stars**: Shoot down 40 UFOs.
- **Skunkworks**: In a single game, complete every Foundry project.
- **Tables Turned**: Shoot down a UFO.
- **Theory...**: Build a Laboratory.
- **...and Practice.**: Build a Workshop.
- **Up and Running**: Build a base facility.
- **The Volunteer**: Make contact with the Ethereal hive mind.
- **We Happy Few**: Complete a mission without losing a soldier.
- **Welcoming Committee**: Kill 150 aliens.
- **Wet Work**: Complete a Very Hard abduction mission in five turns or less on Classic or Impossible difficulty.
- **What Wonders Await**: Complete a Research Project.
- **Worth Every Penny**: Acquire 1000 credits in one month.
- **X Marks the Spot**: Uncover the alien base's location.
- **Xavier**: Mind Control an Ethereal. Single player only.
- **You Have 5 Seconds to Comply**: Build a S.H.I.V.

Comment: He wasn't actually looking for a list of all achievements.  He was looking for a list of the *hidden* achievements.