# Is there a reward for completing XCOM without any casualties?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

Is there a reward for completing XCOM without any casualties (KIA)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I did this on one of my Easy runthroughs of the game, and there's nothing in particular that happens.  There's no associated achievement, either.

There is a post-game statistics screen that compares your performance to the statistics of others, where you can feel proud about your accomplishment, however.

Comment: Theres an achievement for getting through the entire game with the same soldier. If thats your cup of tea

Comment: @Shykin, yeah, but you could get 100 other soldiers killed and get that, so they're not really all that related. :P  That would be an interesting game though - the one hardened vet and the pile of meat shields he used to finish the game...  but I digress.

Comment: was it ironman?

Comment: @SergeyGrinev, no, I have not played through an ironman game with no casualties.

Comment: maybe there is an achievement for that level of luck!

Comment: @SergeyGrinev, nah, we've [accounted for all the achievements](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/87185/what-are-the-hidden-achievements-in-xcom-enemy-unknown) and there isn't one for this, sadly :(

Answer (score 4):

I've finished the game without getting any soldiers killed (required some reloading). As stated above, there is no benefit for doing this other than personal satisfaction. Also, if you want to make sure no soldiers die, don't play the tutorial. Three soldiers will always die on the first tutorial mission and they'll show up on your memorial wall.